# rake db:migrate returns "rake: Is a directory"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, migrate, rakefile, dbmigrate

I've been searching for the answer to this question for a week, but haven't found one.  I'm running Mac OS 10.5.8 if that's relevant.

I'm trying to do the Peepcode tutorial "Meet Rails 3" but when I run the command line `user$ rake db:migrate` I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake: Is a directory - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake (Errno::EISDIR)
from /usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

I found the exact same error at [ruby.pastebin.com](http://ruby.pastebin.com/39MMLxTa) with no answer.  Thanks to anyone willing to help out an aspiring developer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the default install of the ruby interpreter that came with Mac OS X. My suggestion would be to use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to install/manage your gem locations. I haven't read/watched the "Meet Rails 3" stuff, so I am not sure what they are advocating, but I can speak from experience that RVM makes these types of issues go away.

Comment: You're right, I had installed RVM (or so I thought) but I did not edit my .bash_profile to complete the install.  After I did that I was able to run the rake db:migrate command.