# rake: Is a directory (Errno::EISDIR) in Dreamhost while installing Radiant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, dreamhost, radiant

Trying to install radiant on Dreamhost and I got past the part where radiant has put all teh files in the right place (aka `radiant mywebsite.com`).  Now it says to run  `rake production db:bootstrap` but that gives me the error:

```
[colombo]$ rake production db:bootstrap
/home/username/.gems/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake: Is a directory - /home/username/.gems/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake (Errno::EISDIR)
        from /usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/rake:19
```

And I am not sure what this means, any ideas? Something  Thank you.

- Radiant 0.9.1
- Rails 3.0.3
- Ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
- gem 1.5.3

Comment: RVM was my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138161/rake-dbmigrate-returns-rake-is-a-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rake db:migrate returns "rake: Is a directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138161/rake-dbmigrate-returns-rake-is-a-directory)